# UIScrollView does white space and doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scenario in mind, which I tried to implement but to no avail- Put a scrolling view with a text box, all of that within page controller.

Here's what I've done- UIPageViewController->ViewController with data ->UIView ->UIScrollView -> UITextView.

What it does? Well, other than scrolling a bit (not to show all of the text) and showing a weird white bar at the bottom, nothing.

Useful snippets of code- basically I linked my height constraint, and then in code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

//CGSize sizeThatShouldFitTheContent = [_textView sizeThatFits:_textView.frame.size];

self.theScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(self.theScrollView.frame.origin.x, self.theScrollView.frame.origin.y, 320, 2000);//[_theScrollView sizeThatFits:_theScrollView.frame.size];

_heightOfText.constant = 2000; //sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height;

//_textView.frame = CGRectMake(_textView.frame.origin.x, _textView.frame.origin.y, sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.width, sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height);
_textView.scrollEnabled = NO;

NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(self.theScrollView.frame));

self.theScrollView.scrollEnabled  = YES;
}
```

But nope.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you set contentSize?

Comment: AFAIK it's not valid anymore while using iOS 7 & Auto Sizing?

Comment: Try putting a view between the scroll view and the textview.  This will give the scroll view some bounds.

Comment: Do you mean a scroll view->view->text view hierarchy or scroll view->view, text view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue- apparently I should call a selector...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
// Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height + 40);
    [self performSelector:@selector(adjustScrollViewContentSize) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void)adjustScrollViewContentSize
{
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4000, 4000);
}
```